# Does any theory of infinite quantities provide info for $-1$ raised to infinite power, its absolute value, finite part and a series or integral form?

Tags: exponentiation, infinity, nonstandard-analysis, surreal-numbers

I've heard about surreal numbers, hyperreal numbers, Hardy fields, nonstandard analysis, cardinal ariththmetic, ordinal arithmetic, games, etc.

My impression is that neither of them can exactly show the result of the following operation: $(-1)^w$, where $w$ is some infinite number from that theory.

The only theory that exactly gives a result is [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) ${\overline {\mathbb {R} }}$, where, of course, $(-1)^\infty=0$ (because of Cesàro mean).

Am I correct in my skepticism about all these theories?

Comment: I don't know what you are "skeptic" about. $(-1)^\infty$ has no well-defined meaning. Why should it have? What is $\mbox{apple}^{\mbox{pear}}$?

Comment: @RobArthan What you define has well-defined meaning. These theories do not define $(-1)^w$, where $w$ is infinite. And no, I am NOT asking about $(-1)^\infty$ (which I know what would be, and shown in the question).

Comment: I have no idea what your are talking about. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @RobArthan it is totally clear. All tbhose theories introduce infinite quantities but cannot show a single example of a result of $(-1)^w$, where $w$ is an infinite quantity. This means they really do not sufficiently define the entities with which they deal.

Comment: The question, as I see it @RobArthan, is acknowledging that $(-1)^\infty$ is under most (*if not all*) normal circumstances a meaningless expression which is either undefined or at least ill-defined.  It asks if there does exist any context in which meaning can be assigned to the expression, either through the use of Cesaro means or otherwise and replacement of the symbol $\infty$ with any other related infinite object.

Comment: @Anixx "*This means they really do not sufficiently define the entities with which they deal*" I disagree with this statement.  All it means is that the operation of exponentiation is not defined given certain inputs... but we knew this already that exponentiation suffers from problems when negative quantities are involved, not to mention the difficulties surrounding infinite quantities in general.

Comment: @JMoravitz the symbol $\infty$ is meaningful only in extended real line ${\overline {\mathbb {R} }}$. In all other mentioned theories it is meaningless, so what are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of hyperreal numbers (defined using ultrapowers, for instance), $(-1)^w$ is defined for any infinite hypernatural number $w$.  Specifically, $(-1)^w=1$ if $w$ is even and $(-1)^w=-1$ if $w$ is odd.  More generally, $(-1)^w$ can be defined as a hypercomplex number for any hyperreal $w$ in the same way as it is defined for reals, as $\exp(i\pi w)$.  (Of course, just as for real numbers, this is only one possible "branch" of the exponential; you could similarly say $(-1)^w$ is $\exp((i\pi+2ki\pi)w)$ for any hyperinteger $k$.)

I would also mention that $(-1)^\infty$ is usually considered to be undefined in the context of the extended real numbers.  There may be contexts where it is convenient to define it to be $0$, but this is certainly not a widespread convention.

Comment: Thanks. I see they define $(-1)^w$ trivially.

Comment: By the way, does not this depend on the arbitrary choice of the ultrafilter?

Answer (score 1):

There are somewhat natural sine and cosine functions on the class $\mathbf{No}$ of surreal numbers. The class of zeroes of $\sin$ is $\pi \ \mathbf{Oz}$ where $\mathbf{Oz}$ is Conway's ring of omnific integers (a class of "integers" for $\mathbf{No}$).

For $a \in \mathbb{No}$, one can define $(-1)^a:=\cos(a \pi)+i\sin(a \pi) \in \mathbf{No}[i]$ (algebraic closure), which yields $(-1)^{a+b}=(-1)^a (-1)^b$ for all $a,b \in \mathbf{No}$. Note that for $z \in \mathbf{Oz}$, we have $(-1)^z=1$ if $z$ is even and $(-1)^z=-1$ if $z$ is odd.

Now I don't claim that this definition is useful or interesting. Is it the right definition of $(-1)^a$? To answer that, one should first say what one expects of such an operation...

Comment: Can they give an example ofva particular number? So that - 1 to that number is 1?

Comment: @Anixx There is a surreal number which corresponds to the ordinal $\omega$. It is even, so $(-1)^{\omega}=1$ as per the definition above.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. How do they know omega is even? Is it an axiom?

Comment: @Anixx The class $\mathbf{Oz}$ is a direct sum $\mathbf{Oz}=\mathbf{No}_{\succ} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ where the group $\mathbf{No}_{\succ}$ is closed under product by a real number, hence contains only even elements. And $\omega \in \mathbf{No}_{\succ}$ because this class is that of numbers whose expression as series contains only infinite terms.

Comment: I did not understand anything. "numbers whose expression as series contains only infinite terms" - $\omega$'s expression contains only infinite terms? What expression? What is $\mathbf{No}_{\succ}$?

Comment: @Anixx Surreal numbers can be expressed as Hahn series. You will find more information on that by looking at Conway's "On Numbers and Games", or Gonshor's "An Introduction to the theory of surreal numbers". Maybe a quicker way to get the basics yet is Alessandro Berarducci's article "Surreal numbers, exponentiation and derivations".

Comment: thanks. I wonder why they think their surreal numbers include the "ordinals" but not say, rates of grow and Hardy fields.

Comment: @Anixx They include ordinals canonically by construction, whereas the inclusion of Hardy fields requires some form of the axiom of choice and inclusions are not unique or canonical in general.

Comment: I wonder why the think their $\{\mathbb{N}|\}$ should be equivalent to $\omega$-ordinal. Particularly, 1. Why do they think that this ordinal should be the simplest, 2. Why do they think that it should correspond to exactly one surreal number and not to several ones.

Comment: If {1,3,5,7,...} (even numbers corresponds to $\omega$ ordinal (I was told so), then how surreal number $\omega$ can be even?

Comment: @Anixx It is even by definition of $\mathbf{Oz}$ and so on.